# Opaque white background with rgba displays grey over white background?

Tags: css, colors, opacity

I added a transparent background on a div, over a white background with like that:

```
body {
    background: white;
}

.opaque-white {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="opaque-white">
        Area with opaque (opacity: 0.95) background.
    </div>

</body>
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/DvYCA/4/

but for some reason the color of the div shows grey instead of white. Opaque white over white should display...white, right?

Or am I mistaken?

EDIT:
I'm adding a screenshot of the problem. It's a very subtle difference, yet noticeable in some screens. To actually understand the difference, try color picking the left side of the image, with the right area.
[image: Difference between white and transparent-white-over-solid-white :)]

Comment: Are you using IE5, Netscape or something ?

Comment: @j08691 haha I'm so using that whenever someone mentions something being white :')

Comment: RGBA is not support in all browsers which could be the issue:  http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: what browser are you seeing this behavior in? Im not seeing it in latest Firefox 25

Comment: I'm viewing it on the latest Chrome version (31) in Mac OS.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot to see what I mean, maybe by color picking the different areas in photoshop or changing the contrast to see the actual difference.

Comment: @SpirosMartzoukos Having the same problem in Firefox 26.0.1 on Android 4.4. Adding `div with background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);` on top of `div with background: #FFF` it's becoming greyish.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Were you able to get this working? I'm tempted to do this and test it in Windows to see if it's a Mac thing.

Comment: Same thing with Windows.

Answer (score 8):

It's not your screen. The color picker does not lie. I see the bug is still present in Chrome 38 and Canary 40. The thing that worked for me was to add `transform: translateZ(0);` to the .opaque-white div.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug: Chrome composites and outputs rgb(254,254,254) while Safari outputs rgb(255,255,255). Interestingly it doesn't seem to matter what alpha value you use, Chrome always outputs the same colour. It only shows full white if you have an alpha value of 0 or 1, anything inbetween results in a subtle off-white.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot appears to show the desired effect - it appears white to me, and opening it in photoshop shows one side at 255,255,255 an the other at 254,254,254.

Have you checked it on a different monitor? It appears to me that the solution (or the problem rather) is actually local - perhaps your screen or some corrupted .icm file.

Can you try using a hex value and the opacity attribute?

```
.opaque-white {
background: #ffffff;
opacity:.95;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gv59a/

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem and found that a difference can be observed between two different monitors.

On my main monitor I see the grey, whereas on my secondary monitor I see white.

Different display technology uses slightly different algorithms to calculate what to display for each pixel and any display technology may have degraded in various ways that might effect the the precise.

I also found that viewing angle can emphasise the effect http://www.techmind.org/lcd/colour.html.

Try viewing your site / examples on different monitors.